# Android; Dynamic buttons layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dynamiclayout

I have a list filled with values and a list with questions, some elements in the value list have more than 1 element, so for example

question[2] = Light
question[3] = Toppings

value[2] = on / off
value[3] = cheese / peppers / oranges / apples
(i split these values on " / ")

now i want use buttons in place for values ,  for every single question and value in the lists.

is this possible and if yes what is the best approach to create such a layout?

full example: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you list is static and small you way consider creating same using the simple layout, using `textview` for the questions and `buttons` for the values.

Or

You can use the `recyclerview` with `GridLayoutManager` ans set the column count dynamically as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51244629/7200713) .