# show 9 items in recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager

Tags: java, android

How to display recycle view items in three rows and three columns using grid layout manager horizontally that add value vertically increase similar to the following figure

```
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9
```

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244151/recyclerviews-gridlayoutmanager-dynamic-span-count

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView with adapter and write this line:

```
final GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),3);
catProRecycleView.setLayoutManager(manager);
catProRecycleView.setAdapter(categoryProductAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that your GridLayoutManager is HORIZONTAL. Like this:

`gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);`

3 is number of rows.

More info:
[How to implement horizontal gridlayoutmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863174/how-to-implement-horizontal-gridlayoutmanager)